# Checkbox input not changing value in a logical standpoint

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework

I'm using AngularJS with the Ionic framework to make a hybrid mobile application and having an issue with something that seems really basic. Just creating a simply remember me button.

Here is my controller:

```
function loginController($scope, $state) {
    $scope.formData = {
        email: null,
        password: null
    };

    $scope.remember = false;

    $scope.doLogin = function() {
        alert("Remember me? - " + $scope.remember);
        console.log($scope.formData);
    };
}
```

Here is my page:

```
<ion-view hide-nav-bar="true">
  <ion-header-bar>
    <h1 class="title">Login</h1>
  </ion-header-bar>
  <ion-content>
    <form>
      <div class="list">
        <label class="item item-input">
          <span class="input-label">Username</span>
          <input type="text" ng-model="formData.email">
        </label>
        <label class="item item-input">
          <span class="input-label">Password</span>
          <input type="password" ng-model="formData.password">
        </label>
        <label class="item item-checkbox">
            <label class="checkbox">
                <input type="checkbox" ng-model="remember">
            </label>
            Remember me? - {{remember}}
        </label>
        <label class="item">
          <button ng-click="doLogin()" class="button button-block button-positive" type="submit">Log in</button>
        </label>
      </div>
    </form>
  </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

The issue is that when I press the button and `doLogin` is called, the alert will show whatever value is originally declared. In this example it will print out the following output:

```
Remember me? - false
```

However, the `{{remember}}` in the document represents the correct `true/false` value of the checkbox. If I was to change the original declaration of remember to `$scope.remember = null;` Then the alert would always output:

```
Remember me? - null
```

I'm a little confused as to what the issue is considering the remember value is obviously being updated considering the `{{remember}}` is pulling it up.

Also the username and password are updating fine, which leaves me absolutely stumped.

Comment: Is there a reason you only have `formData` and not `$scope.formData` above?

Comment: @Malkus - Typo while removing the irrelevant code.

Comment: are you sure that clicking on button will not submit ? therefore it will reload the controller initialization each time ...

Comment: @moncef - Absolutely sure.